# Generalizing over adding unsigned and signed integer types

Tags: rust, integer

I want to have a Rust function that allows adding an `u32` (`u64`, `u128`) type to an `i32` (`i64`, `i128`) type while checking for overflow.

My implementation:

```
/// Add u32 to i32. In case of an overflow, return None.
fn checked_add_i32_u32(a: i32, b: u32) -> Option<i32> {
    let b_half = (b / 2) as i32;
    let b_rem = (b % 2) as i32;

    Some(a.checked_add(b_half)?.checked_add(b_half)?
        .checked_add(b_rem)?)
}

/// Add u64 to i64. In case of an overflow, return None.
fn checked_add_i64_u64(a: i64, b: u64) -> Option<i64> {
    let b_half = (b / 2) as i64;
    let b_rem = (b % 2) as i64;

    Some(a.checked_add(b_half)?.checked_add(b_half)?
        .checked_add(b_rem)?)
}
```

I have another similar one that does the same for `u128` and `i128`. I feel like I am repeating myself. My tests for those functions also look very similar.

Is there a way I could refactor my code and have just one function instead? I am not sure how to generalize over the relationship between `u32` and `i32` (or `u64` and `i64`, `u128` and `i128`).

Comment: Simplify by not using the last `?`: `a.checked_add(b_half)?.checked_add(b_half)?.checked_add(b_rem)`

Comment: @Shepmaster: I will, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a macro:

```
trait CustomAdd: Copy {
    type Unsigned;

    fn my_checked_add(self, b: Self::Unsigned) -> Option<Self>;
}

macro_rules! impl_custom_add {
    ( $i:ty, $u:ty ) => {
        impl CustomAdd for $i {
            type Unsigned = $u;

            fn my_checked_add(self, b: $u) -> Option<$i> {
                let b_half = (b / 2) as $i;
                let b_rem = (b % 2) as $i;

                Some(self.checked_add(b_half)?.checked_add(b_half)?
                    .checked_add(b_rem)?)
            }
        }
    }
}

impl_custom_add!(i32, u32);
impl_custom_add!(i64, u64);
// etc.

#[test]
fn tests() {
    assert_eq!(123.my_checked_add(10_u32), Some(133));
}
```

Comment: For information, I use this strategy [in my crates](https://gitlab.com/Boiethios/radix_fmt_rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L66) and it works well.